# Ошибка "delphi msxml is not installed" при создании TXMLDocument внутри class function в отдельном Unit

Tags: delphi, xml

Есть `class function` внутри которой мне нужно работать с XML текстом
делаю так:

```
unit api;
interface
uses
  ...
  Xml.XMLDoc;

type
  TAPI = class
    ...
    class function GetAccount(...): TAccount;
  end;

implementation

class function TAPI.GetAccount(..): TAccount;
var
  MyXML: String;
  XMLDocument: TXMLDocument;
begin
  //MyXML := Some XML text
  XMLDocument := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  try
    XMLDocument.XML.Text := MyXML;
    XMLDocument.Active := True; // здесь ошибка
  finally
    XMLDocument.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Получаю ошибку

> "delphi msxml is not installed"

Если проделать аналогичное в главном Unit где есть Form, ошибки нет. 
Как исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если `TXMLDocument` используется не в GUI, а в отдельном потоке или в консольном приложении, нужно руками вызывать `CoInitialize`:

```
  var
    XMLDocument: IXMLDocument;
  ...
  begin
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      XMLDocument := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
      try
       ...
      finally
        // Интерфейс должен быть удалён до вызова CoUninitialize
        XMLDocument := nil;  
      end;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
```

В [доках](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Rio/en/TXMLDocument_use_case_(Delphi)) об этом, в общем-то, сказано. Но кто же их читает?

Comment: скажите, если XMLDocument будет создаваться как свойство объекта в отдельном потоке, то CoInitialize(nil) нужно ставить в начало конструктора, а CoUninitialize в конец деструктора? Если да то, CoInitialize(nil) или CoInitialize(self)?

Comment: @ArtGrek13 если в отдельном потоке - то ставить в начало Execute, а не конструктора. И в соответствии с доками - CoInitialize(nil)

Comment: @ArtGrek13 У `TThread` конструктор выполняется в контексте потока вызывающей функции, поэтому - нет, там нельзя вызывать инициализацию. Её надо выполнять в контексте того потока, в котором будет использоваться объект.

Comment: @zed Если мне не изменяет память - то создание TXMLDocument без указания Owner-а приводит к тому, что он ведет себя как интерфейс. И для правильной работы в этом случае нужно объявлять XMLDocument как IXMLDocument (иначе уничтожится сразу после конструктора), ну и убрать Free.

Comment: @kami Про Owner ничего не скажу, но вот то, что надо использовать `IXMLDocument` так это 100%. А Free надо не просто убрать, а сделать обнуление интерфейса (XMLDocument := nil). См. подробнее тут:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20483009

Comment: @kami да нужно объявлять XMLDocument как IXMLDocument

Comment: @zed все понял. Спасибо

Comment: @zed ну, не совсем :) Посмотрел - да, подсчет ссылок завязан на `if Owner is TComponent`. Собственно, брошенный на форму XMLDocument, фигурирующий именно как TXMLDocument, наглядно показывает, что подсчет ссылок не используется.